# Why is my Verify.Bunit test failing and not producing a received file?

Tags: testing, blazor, verify, bunit, verify-tests

I am using the `Verify.Xunit` and `Verify.Bunit` packages in my test project but they have started failing and I can't figure out why.

Example simple test - just renders a component:

```csharp
[Fact]
public Task TestInputBaseRendering_Default()
{
  //Arrange: render the base markup
  var cut = this.Render(TestInputBaseRendering_Default_Markup);

  // Act: 

  // Assert: 
  return Verify(cut);
}
```

The first time I run the test, it produces a `received` file and an empty `verified` file and launches my diff tool where I can copy the `received` text into the `verified` file and save - this is expected normal behaviour.

Sample output now saved as `TestInputBaseRendering_Default.verified.html`:

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="" id="id1" blazor:onchange="1" blazor:elementreference="Guid_1">
```

When I then re-run the test it should produce the same output (debugging and inspecting the object being passed to `Verify(cut)` shows the correct output) - save it in `TestInputBaseRendering_Default.received.html` and compare this to `TestInputBaseRendering_Default.verified.html`

If there was a difference, it should launch my diff tool to inspect the variance in output.

What is actually happening is the test fails again does not open the diff tool and does not save a `received` file:

Test result:

```
Message: 
VerifyException : Directory: C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxxx\tests\xxxxx.test\Inputs\SBInputBaseTests
Delete:
  - InputBaseRenderingTests.TestInputBaseRendering_Label.verified.html.bak
  - InputBaseRenderingTests.TestInputBaseRendering_Label.verified.txt.bak
Equal:
  - Received: InputBaseRenderingTests.TestInputBaseRendering_Label.received.txt
    Verified: InputBaseRenderingTests.TestInputBaseRendering_Label.verified.txt
  - Received: InputBaseRenderingTests.TestInputBaseRendering_Label.received.html
    Verified: InputBaseRenderingTests.TestInputBaseRendering_Label.verified.html
```

I have no idea how to resolve that the test now fails every time and does not save the `received` file.

I have checked by debugging the test that the component is rendered correctly each time - the problem lies somewhere in the `Verify` system, for which I cannot find any additional logging or debugging help.

Comment: I'm using Verify as shown in the code - the question is not about whether the results are consistent, but why Verify is not even producing a "received" file as it should. If you can think of  wording I should change to clarify that please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it isnt launching a diff tool since the inputs match the verified files.

it is telling you that there are 2 unexpected files that should be deleted

- InputBaseRenderingTests.TestInputBaseRendering_Label.verified.html.bak
- InputBaseRenderingTests.TestInputBaseRendering_Label.verified.txt.bak

if u use diffenginetray (https://github.com/VerifyTests/DiffEngine/blob/main/docs/tray.md) it will automate this. or u can use one of the other approaches to managing snapshots

https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify#snapshot-management

re winmerge

> Ensure that file backups are either disabled or changed to use a Global backup folder

Comment: So, WinMerge is probably creating the .bak files and Verify doesn't like them - I see